# OS X: frequent discoveryd warnings in console

Tags: console, macos

Here's an example from the console log:

```
29.05.15 09:27:23,475 discoveryd[89]: Basic Warn DD_Warn: Bad count; corrupt TXT RDATA
```

I'm trying to find the cause of some frequent slowness on my iMac so I'm inspecting the console log regularly. These are one of the messages I can't get rid of and I can't seem to find an issue for.

Any idea where this may come from? They seem to appear every few hours.

10.10.3, late 2012 iMac.

Comment: Is there any other salient information around that area? I've seen that as part of a DNS issue

Comment: You're not alone ... According to Mac Rumors, the "discoveryd" is being replaced with the older mDNSResponder in 10.10.4 (which is not released yet)  http://www.macrumors.com/2015/05/26/apple-discoveryd-replaced-with-mdnsresponder/   No idea when 10.10.4 will be released; or if it will ultimately include these changes; but, it may be a wasted effort to spend too much time chasing this one down.

Comment: I would agree with Kent. 10.10.4 will be out sooner rather than later and Apple is killing discoveryd. What is actually slowing down?